# Is it possible to select a variable of an outer query from a subquery?

Tags: sql

Basically, I'm trying to reference the row currently being evaluated and use it in a subquery.

```
...
CASE WHEN [type] IN (1, 2) THEN (
      SELECT companyName FROM Company 
          WHERE id = (SELECT companyId FROM [TransactionParty] 
                      WHERE id = _this.fromTransactionPartyId))
END AS senderCompanyName 
...
```

Where "_this.fromTransactionPartyId" is referring to the fromtransactionPartyId column of the current row where [type] IN (1, 2). Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. That makes the subqeury _correlated_!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: What's the `else` going to be? It looks like you just want a left join. `left outer join Company as c on c.id = <T>.fromTransactionPartyId and <T>."type" in (1, 2)`

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible.
Are you trying to fetch companyName from the Company table only when it has a respective entry in the TransactionParty table? In that case, you use inner join:

```
Select c.CompanyName from Company c inner join TransactionParty t on c.id = t.companyId and c.fromTransactionPartyId=t.id
```

Comment: I'm trying to fetch companyName from the Company table where the transactionPartyID column on the [Transaction] table equals the id column on the [TransactionParty] table. The case posted above is part of a query on the [Transaction] table.

Comment: In that case, the inner join is the solution.

Answer (score -1):

That's perfectly possible. You just need to name your identifiers correctly with the correct table like `tab1.Id`:

```
select 
  case when id in (1,2) then (SELECT value FROM tab2 
          WHERE tab2.id = (SELECT id2 FROM idreltab 
                      WHERE id1 = tab1.Id))
  else 'not in (1, 2)' end
from tab1
```

(I replaced your table names with tab1[unknown], tab2[Company] and IdRelTab[TransactionParty])

See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/23d14a/3) as example (in oracle, as you didn't mention a DBMS)

However, I'd try to use joins instead of subqueries as they're far more performance friendly